# "ValueError: bad marshal data" with Keras on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, keras, tensorflow

I am currently having issue with Keras on Windows 10. I was trying to search for my problem a lot and tried different ways but unfortunately I cannot fix it yet. I would very appreciate your help!

I was trying to install Keras 2.1.1, Tensorflow-gpu 1.4.0 and Python 3.6 on a conda env on Windows 10 (later I tried to create another conda env with Python 3.5.2 but it still didn't work). I got the `UnicodeDecodeError: 'rawunicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 111-112: truncated \uXXXX` while I was trying to save my model. I then follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847376/keras-model-to-json-error-rawunicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-posi) by adding `replace(b'\\',b'/')` in `generic_utils.py` and it works well.

However, after that I open another file to load my model, and this error appears: `ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)` (if it is in env with python 3.6) and `SystemError: unknown opcode` (if it is in env with python 3.5.2).

I tried to create new envs and reinstall with Keras 2.0.8 with python 3.6/3.5 and tried to change tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0, but it didn't work.

Some links I have tried to follow:

1. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/7297
2. [Encoding error when installing Keras on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328528/encoding-error-when-installing-keras-on-windows-10)

Does any one know how to fix it or any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

P/S: other information (not sure if it helps): I am using `GTX 1080Ti` and `sublime text 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found a solution for my question above. Sorry for my ignorance.

The problem has nothing to do with Keras or Tensorflow problem. Instead, it is related to python 3 problem. Python 3 cannot decode the special character `\u` on Windows.

So the solution is pretty simple: you just need to change your path to the absolute path, such as `'C:/users/.../'` or move your files, change the name of the file to other path, as long as it does not contain the special character `\u`.